# NullPointerException while implementing RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement RecyclerView to display list of items in a Fragment.

Fragment Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchFragment extends BaseFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<StringBuilder> {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SearchAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private String searchQuery;

    private User user;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public SearchFragment() {
    }

    public static SearchFragment newInstance() {
        SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setSearchQuery(String searchQuery) {
        this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    public void search() {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(API.DISH_SEARCH_KEY, searchQuery);
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LoaderConstants.DISH_SEARCH_LOADER_ID, bundle, SearchFragment.this).forceLoad();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // thrown when Fragment not attached to Activity
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            user = new Gson().fromJson(getArguments().getString(API.USER_KEY), User.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        search();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<StringBuilder> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {

        String searchQuery = bundle.getString(API.DISH_SEARCH_KEY);
        String url = String.format(API.DISH_SEARCH_URL, searchQuery);

        bundle.putString(API.URL_KEY, url);
        bundle.putString(API.TYPE_KEY, API.TYPE_GET);

        return new CravyAsyncLoader(getActivity(), bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<StringBuilder> loader, StringBuilder data) {

        if (Util.isEmptyJsonResponse(data)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No dishes found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        List<Dish> dishes;
        try {
            // Convert JSONArray response to List<Dish>
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Dish>>() {
            }.getType();
            dishes = (List<Dish>) new Gson().fromJson(data.toString(), listType);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong. Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (dishes != null) {
            mAdapter = new SearchAdapter(dishes, SearchFragment.this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<StringBuilder> loader) {
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.List;

public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Dish> mDishes;
    private Fragment fragment;

    public SearchAdapter(List<Dish> dishes, Fragment fragment) {
        mDishes = dishes;
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public LinearLayout mView;
        private Fragment fragment;

        public ViewHolder(LinearLayout itemView, Fragment fragment) {
            super(itemView);
            this.fragment = fragment;
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dish_id);
            String id = textView.getText().toString();

            Dish dish = getDishById(id);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(API.DISH_KEY, new Gson().toJson(dish));

            // Create new fragment and transaction
            DishDetailsFragment dishDetailsFragment = DishDetailsFragment.newInstance(bundle);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, dishDetailsFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public SearchAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, fragment);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        ((TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.dish_id)).setText(mDishes.get(position).getId());
        ((TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.dish_name)).setText(mDishes.get(position).getName());
        ((TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name)).setText(mDishes.get(position).getRestaurantId());
        try {
            ((TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.price)).setText(String.valueOf(mDishes.get(position).getPrice().getValue()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ((TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.price)).setText("No Price Available");
        }
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDishes.size();
    }

    public Dish getDishById(String id) {
        for (Dish dish : mDishes) {
            if (dish.getId().equals(id))
                return dish;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting error in `Adapter` at line

```
    ((TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.dish_id)).setText(mDishes.get(position).getId());
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.fonduetech.cravy.adapter.SearchAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SearchAdapter.java:87)
        at com.fonduetech.cravy.adapter.SearchAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SearchAdapter.java:21)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4138)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3448)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1000)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:710)
        at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:982)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:723)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewR
```

I tried to debug app. It shows `mView` as `null`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public ViewHolder(LinearLayout itemView, Fragment fragment) {
        super(itemView);
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.mView = itemView; //this line is missing
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u use Android Studio ??

If Yes just include this in the build.grade :

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

and after that just sync the grade or just press the gradle button at the top. I guess this will give u some results

Answer (score 0):

If your RecyclerView adapter does not have data means you are not calling setAdapter then it's return Error.

So by default you have to set invisible property of the RecyclerView if you have data then first set data and after then set Visiable Property of the RecyclerView.